# Ornaments command move text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, book-design, text-decorations, pgfornament

I'm experiencing a glitch with a decoration command, which moves a bit the text on the page.  Here's a stripped down version of the code I'm trying to fix:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,medium]{titlesec}

% Main header :
\newpagestyle{principal}{
    \sethead[\thepage][][\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}]{\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}}{}{\thepage}
    \headrule
}

% Add ornementations to corners :
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\newcommand*{\pageornament}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\color{#2}%
    \node[anchor=north west,xshift=0.5in+2mm,yshift=-2mm] at (current page.north west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=north east,xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm] at (current page.north east){%
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=v]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south west,xshift=0.5in+2mm,yshift=2mm] at (current page.south west){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=h]{#1}};
    \node[anchor=south east,xshift=-2mm,yshift=2mm] at (current page.south east){% 
    \pgfornament[width=2cm,symmetry=c]{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{principal}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\pageornament{41}{gray}

Some funny line\footnote{Some weird footnote text.}

\newpage

Another line

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview of what this code is doing (we need two compilations to see the result) :

[image]

If you desactivate the decoration command **\pageornament{41}{gray}** (just after the chapter's title), the text moves back to its proper position.  Why is the ornament command moving the block of text?  How can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: I suggest using `eso-pic` to place the ornament.

Comment: This is the normal indentation at the beginning of a paragraph. Note that the first paragraph of a section/chapter is not indented.

Comment: @Andreas Matthias, the command change also the vertical position of the text.  I don’t want this to happen. How can I change the command to prevent the text Motion ?

Comment: @Symbol, how?  Could you suggest a macro to do the same decoration ?

Comment: @Cham: Your first paragraph is  more or less empty, but nevertheless it is a complete paragraph. Actually it contains two spaces from your macro where you did not comment all newline characters. Your ornament is put into a box, and even if the dimensions of your box would be 0pt x 0pt it would still be a box, ie a complete paragaph. And the second paragaph is shifted down. -- Don't go this way. Try it with eso-pic.

Comment: @Andreas Matthias Okay, I’ll switch to eso-pic. But I don’t know how to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\AddToHook` macro to extend the `\shipout` macro to output the contents of a zero-sized `picture`, at the top left (0,0) of the page.

```
% pagedecoprob.tex  Try for decorative page margins

\documentclass{book} \usepackage{geometry}  %%%% SE 568730  or
%\documentclass{memoir}  %%%% SE 568730

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% seems like picture can now cope with actual values
% inset from page edges, change this to suit
\newlength{\linset} \setlength{\linset}{\baselineskip} 
% x coordinate of RHS 
\newlength{\rloc} \setlength{\rloc}{\paperwidth} \addtolength{\rloc}{-\linset}
% (-) y coordinate of bottom location
\newlength{\bloc} \setlength{\bloc}{\paperheight} \addtolength{\bloc}{-\linset}

% the decorative elements and their placements
\newcommand{\corners}{% 
  \put(\linset,-\linset){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{linset, -linset}}  % top left
  \put(\rloc,-\linset){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{rloc, -linset}}      % top right
  \put(\linset,-\bloc){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{linset, -bloc}}      % bottom left
  \put(\rloc,-\bloc){\makebox(0,0)[br]{rloc, -bloc}}          % bottom right
}

% use LaTeX arrows as the decorative elements
\renewcommand{\corners}{%
  \put(\linset,-\linset){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\Huge$\nearrow$}}  % top left
  \put(\rloc,-\linset){\makebox(0,0)[tr]{\Huge$\nwarrow$}}    % top right
  \put(\linset,-\bloc){\makebox(0,0)[bl]{\Huge$\searrow$}}    % bottom left
  \put(\rloc,-\bloc){\makebox(0,0)[br]{\Huge$\swarrow$}}      % bottom right
}

% put decorative elements on this and future pages 
\AddToHook{shipout/background}[mypic]{\corners}

\chapter{First}
\textbf{Added To Hook}
\lipsum[1-12]

\textbf{Removed from Hook}

\RemoveFromHook{shipout/background}[mypic]

\lipsum[1-10]

\textbf{Added to Hook}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}[mypic]{\corners}

\lipsum[1-10]
  
\end{document}
```

With thanks to @ulrikefischer for showing me the `\...Hook` code (answer to [How do I put (or not) something on every page independently of headers and footers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568846)).

[image]